# How to assign each frame a mouse position if the number of mouse position data exceeds the number of frames in the video

Tags: javascript, video

I am building an application that lets user record their screen and it sends the **mouse coordinates** on mouse move event through websockets.

Now I am sending the mouse coordinates and the recorded video through websockets to the backend and using opencv to decode the video frames there and draw a custom mouse on top of each frames based on the mouse coordinates received from frontend on mouse move event.

But if the mouse was moving too fast, the number of mouse coordinates items exceeds the number of frames the video have, I am not sure how can I draw the exceeded coordinates data on top of frames that are less than the data

Suppose I have a recorded video with 10 frames.
I receive mouse coordinates for 30 points during the video.

```js
mousepositions = [
{"x": 97, "y": 1},
{"x": 125, "y": 14},
{"x": 157, "y": 32},
{"x": 186, "y": 45},
{"x": 223, "y": 62},
{"x": 290, "y": 90},
...
]
```